# Send print with batchfile to wireless printer

Tags: wireless-networking, batch, printing, printer

I'm tryining to send at print to my wireless Cannon printer with a batchfile.

So far I ended up with something like this:

```
PRINT /D:192.168.1.121/cannon C:\Users\admin\Documents\test.docx
```

But the printer doesn't register it.

Comment: The print command doesn't know anything about printer drivers nor (binary) file types, aside from outputting a prefabricated print file (specific to the printer) it's nowadays pretty useless. Better use the print method of the registered file type with a script language that supports that (vbs/powershell) Read [this](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/printfiles.php) on the issue.

Comment: Might or might not help to spell 'Canon' correctly, too

Answer (score 0):

A .docx file is in Microsoft Word Open XML Format. This format is understood by Word and similar applications, but it is not understood by any printer. The only way to print a document like this is to open it in Word or a compatible application like OpenOffice Writer, and print from there. Even right-clicking it in Windows Explorer and selecting Print will start Word and print it that way.

It is possible to print some text documents or PDFs from a command line, but only with printers which support that. Your "wireless Cannon printer" is almost certainly a low-cost GDI style printer. Such printers do not support direct PDF or text printing. If your printer does support it, give me the model number to check, and I'll let you know how to proceed.

However, as I stated earlier, NO printer can print .docx files directly.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to use names instead of ip addresses

`PRINT /D:\\<pcname>\<printersharename>\ <location\test.docx>`

This fixed it.

You're right that it woulden't be able to print, but that wasn't necessary. We're using a different kind of file, wich works perfect with our label printer.